# How to use static imported method with forEach?

Tags: java, foreach, static-methods, java-8, static-import

Is there a way to call `Iterable#forEach` with a statically imported method as argument? I got this to work by typing the fully qualified name for the function, without importing it:

```
Arrays.asList(line).forEach(org.junit.Assert::assertNotNull);
```

Another variant being:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
...
Arrays.asList(line).forEach(Assert::assertNotNull);
```

The reason for this, is I want to `assertNotNull` every element in `line` in a unit test, but I don't like using fully qualified names for that stuff. It would have been nice to just use:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
...
Arrays.asList(line).forEach(assertNotNull);
```

Comment: you could do `Consumer<T> assertNotNull = Assert::assertNotNull` and reuse it everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You'll have to revert to classical lambda notation to do that:

```
Arrays.asList(line).forEach(e-> assertNotNull(e));
```